# Python appending to wrong list?

Tags: python, list, object, pygame

I can make no sense of this problem.  I have a `Player` object and some `Enemy` objects that both inherit from the `Actor` class.  Both `Player` and `Enemy` have `shoot(self)` methods that makes them shoot a bullet.  This bullet is supposed to be added to their respective list of projectiles, but when the program calls `self.projectiles.append(Projectile())` for an enemy, it adds it to the player's list of projectiles.

I've run the program where the only Actor shooting any bullets was the enemies and I watch as `len(player.projectiles)` returns greater and greater values, even though it should not be growing. Any help is appreciated. This block runs every time the program updates, it goes through the `Game` object's list of enemies and updates each one respectively:

```py
for enemy in self.enemies:
    enemy.update(self.player)
```

Here's the `Enemy` class:

```py
class Enemy(Actor):

    def shoot(self):
        image = pygame.transform.rotate(ProjectileImage, self.angle)
        self.projectiles.append(Projectile(self.getCenter()[0] - 6, self.getCenter()[1] - 16, 12, 32, image, 5, self.angle, True))
        shootingSound.play()

    def tryToShoot(self):
        if self.attackCoolDown >= 30:
            self.attackCoolDown = 0
            self.shoot()

    def update(self, player):
        self.pointTowards(player.x, player.y)
        Actor.update(self)
        self.tryToShoot()
```

The `Actor` class initializes `projectiles`:

```py
class Actor(Entity):
    projectiles = []
```

Comment: See https://realpython.com/lessons/class-and-instance-attributes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted code shows `projectiles` as a *class* attribute, not an *instance* attribute.  Thus, all `Actor`s share a single `projectiles` list.  To make separate lists, initialize the attribute inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: And use `self.projectiles`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I didn't know how to make static variables in python, now I do!

Comment: Actually, you don't know how to make static variables: Python doesn't support that concept.  Instance variables may be close enough for your current implementation, but they aren't quite the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `projectiles` as a class varable,both `Enemy` and `Player` inheret the ***same list object*** .

Also,when you ref something using self (and it can't be found in the instance dictionary) , it defaults to the class varable, that is why your player's and enemy's lenths are *both* growing:*they share the same list object*.

To fix this,put the `projectiles=[]` line into the `__init__` method:

**Change:**

```py
class Actor(Entity):
    projectiles = []
```

**To:**

```py
class Actor(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        self.projectiles = []
```

To fix the bug.

PS: You don't seem to have a `update` method in the `Actor` class.
And if you do, using `super().update()` will be more Pythonic than `Actor.update(self)`.

Comment: I do have an update method in Actor but I wasn't aware that I could just call super().update().  Thanks for the help.